# How to batch convert .doc or .docx to .pdf

Tags: command-line, pdf, batch

I need to batch convert a set of `.doc` or `.docx` files to `.pdf` in terminal, not using a GUI.

It would be helpful if I could batch-process multiple files.

I would also like to maintain as much meta-data as possible.

Comment: duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux

Comment: The best answer there is to install another application and use a "pdf printer". What is wrong using a CLI method or will I loose the meta-data

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with oowriter, gscan2pdf or any other GUI method. I was looking for the CLI then I intend to incorporate it into the .bashrc so I could `pdf ~/some_.docx`, thats all. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/104480/3940).

Comment: @Takkat - That answer gets it into duplicate zone for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a odt to pdf?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60778/how-to-convert-a-odt-to-pdf)

Comment: It is not really a dupe. Here we ask for batch and .doc, there for odt (not batch). The answer however would better fit here ;)

Comment: ###### On Mac Install
```bash
brew install --cask libreoffice
``` ###### Convert ```bash
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.odt
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

lowriter can be used as a command line tool (lowriter is a part of LibreOffice)

```
lowriter --convert-to pdf *.doc
convert /home/bodhi/Documents/testdoc2.doc -> /home/bodhi/Documents/testdoc2.pdf using writer_pdf_Export
convert /home/bodhi/Documents/testdoc.doc -> /home/bodhi/Documents/testdoc.pdf using writer_pdf_Export

evince testdoc.pdf
```

I do not have windows, so testdoc download from here

www.mltweb.com/prof/testdoc.doc

Comment: libreofice throws errors using this method, complains of not finding /home/user/documents/test.docx blah

Comment: what command did you use ? Do you have a test.docx ?

Comment: lowriter --convert-to pdf /home/user/Documents/Document compatibility check.docx

Comment: Works perfect for me!

Beware of using "space" character from command line...
When you get to the space character simply press "tab" ;)

Comment: lowriter does not convert docx files correctly. At least not always.

Comment: @ScepticalJule- You should then file a bug report against lowriter.

Comment: When I first tried your suggested `lowriter` command on Ubuntu 12.04, it opened a splash window and froze. I killed it with C-c and tried again without a `DISPLAY` variable. This time it first printed an error about missing display, but convert the document without any problems. Is it expected behavior, that the command can only work without a `DISPLAY` environment variable?

Comment: `[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
`  using https://nces.ed.gov/ccd/Data/zip/sc122a_documentation_052716.zip

Comment: In general, not only just `lowriter` that mostly comes from the distro repos (used to be outdated) but also any version of LibreOffice works well now, i.e.:
``libreoffice7.2 --convert-to pdf *.doc``

Answer (score 9):

I use `unoconv`, which converts all formats supported by `LibreOffice`.

Comment: Just for the record: `$ unoconv myfile.docx` (it creates `myfile.pdf`)

Answer (score 5):

I use the following script:

```
for f in *.doc
do
lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf "$f"
done
```

--headless will prevent Libreoffice from opening 100s of files and eventually crashing if you try this with directories containing a lot of .doc files

Comment: this is the best, works for multiple files

Answer (score 1):

You can also open that folder where you have all the `.doc` or `.docx` files and right click.Then select open terminal here. then type `lowriter --convert-to pdf *.doc`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way is with `unoconv`.

First install the package:

```
sudo apt install unoconv
```

and then convert to pdf using this command:

```
unoconv -f pdf XXYY.docx
```

(Replace `XXYY.docx` with the name of your file.)

Comment: Reasons why you would choose unoconv over other options?

Comment: "Unoconv is deprecated" from https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv