# convert .doc files to .pdf file using imagemagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I want to convert .DOC files into .PDF format using php image library [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) .
When I used

`convert filename.doc filename.pdf`

command in terminal to convert file to .PDF format I got the error

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `ATTENDANCE.doc' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: missing an image filename `ATTENDANCE.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011.
```

Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

Comment: .doc files aren't images. You should try seeing if you can automate LibreOffice Writer or Abiword or something in order to print the documents to PDF.

Answer (score 5):

ImageMagick can't read doc files.

You could try

```
oowriter -pt pdf your_word_file.doc
```

which requires you have the libre/openoffice suite installed.
Note if you have libreoffice, replace `oowriter` with `lowriter`.

See [this other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux) for a similar question.

According to Broam an alternative invocation is

```
oowriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export doc_file.doc –
```

though I haven't tested this.

**Web service**

Alternatively I would also suggest using [Google docs](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/documents/) (now integrated into Google drive) as an alternative if you have a Google account or don't mind making one.

You can upload the doc and it will convert it to pdf for you (or an openoffice format if you prefer).

**Which one should you use?**

Of these two options, the last time I checked Google docs had a higher conversion fidelity.

Comment: About what I was going to say - automate oowriter to do it. :)

Comment: The magic seems to be `oowriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export doc_file.doc`

Comment: lowriter --convert-to pdf  YourDoc.doc worked for me( single case of this https://askubuntu.com/questions/113772/how-to-batch-convert-doc-or-docx-to-pdf)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) as a headless tool to convert docs to pdf:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.doc
```

---

(Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31217832/1329340))