# How do I convert Pocket Word files (PSW) to ODT?

Tags: libreoffice, format-conversion

I have a bunch of PSW (Pocket Word for Pocket PC) files I want to get the text out of. They were copied off an old pocket PC years ago without being converted.

No, I do not have the pocket PC any more, just the files on my Ubuntu machine.

Right now, if I try to open the files, even if I select "Pocket Word" in the file open dialog, it pops up the ASCII filter, which just provides me with reams of ### characters.

A document that was once a dozen pages of text is now 261 pages of ############## with the occasional word thrown in.

The LibreOffice documentation assumes I have Windows and the original Pocket PC with Outlook and a bunch of Microsoft stuff installed. Not particularly useful for a Ubuntu user. :)