# Exporting docx files as PDFs using LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I received a .docx file from a colleague with comments added using the 'Review/Comment' feature in MS Word. I need to convert the document, **including** the comments, into a PDF, but when I use the 'Export as PDF' option in LibreOffice Writer, the comments don't appear in the PDF. I've tried checking 'Export comments' in the PDF Options menu, but it still doesn't seem to work. Is there any way of fixing this? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with LibreOffice 3. Would it work any better with OpenOffice?

Comment: You could install `unoconv` and try it: I've found that it works pretty well with docx files, although I'm not sure about ones with comments: for just one file, enter `unoconv -f pdf file.docx`. If you want to batch convert them, you could adapt the script in my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60778/how-to-convert-a-odt-to-pdf/227652#227652). You could also try saving them as odt and then converting them to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an intermediate conversion into an open document file (`.odt`) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, same libreoffice docx-to-pdf problem here.

Intermediate conversion to odt -> result -> idem dito.
Only one top image shows in the resulting pdf. The rest of the document, the textual part, not.

Saving the docx to jpg or png works. But those formats only take the first page of the two page docx.

The (so-so) solution I could think of was:

1. Save the docx-document as odt-document with libreoffice.
2. Open the odt-document with 'File' -> 'Example in webbrowser' from within libreoffice gui.
3. Print to pdf from within browser (Firefox here. Edited a little with the 'Print Edit WE' add-on.). The layout is slightly different but almost the same as that of the original docx/odt, with all the content there.

If Firefox can do it, why can't libreoffice do it ;-)

System details:

- LibreOffice 6.4.7.2 40(Build:2)
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with Lubuntu skin

Greets.

Comment: Try OnlyOffice. It has excellent MS office compatibility