# How to convert Powerpoint ppsx (presentation) to pdf?

Tags: pdf

I have a ppsx file with images that I want usable in other environments than office suites: it would be perfect having them as separate images. I could then use them directly; or create a pdf from them (I find easy converting images to pdf and extracting images from pdf). Or may it is possible to convert the ppsx file into pdf with a command or GUI?

Comment: A general solution for all documents supported by LO can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60778/how-to-convert-an-odt-to-pdf/236416#236416

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LibreOffice supports exporting of presentations to pdf format.

All you have to do is open the presentation in Libreoffice (Impress, the PowerPoint equivalent), then go to `File > Export to PDF`.

Answer (score 1):

1. In LibreOfficeImpress Click **Ctrl+P**
2. then from **options** tab select **print to file**
3. after that make you settings of how file must look like from **page layout** tab.
4. click **print to file** button at the bottom of dialogue box.
5. Enter name of file (any name you want).
6. Hurra you are up.