# Mass convert Word & PPT to PDF software

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any software to convert Microsoft Word and Powerpoint files to PDF documents in a batch without having to open each one individually? Either a graphical or terminal method will be suitable.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/60778/how-to-convert-an-odt-to-pdf - any file that loads in Libre Office can also be exported to PDF

Comment: both Open Office and Libre Office can convert your word and presentation file to pdf, just goto file menu and select export option.

Comment: But OP seems to do this without having to open each Word or PPT file in LibreOffice *and then converting that file* to PDF.

Comment: @vasa1 There are several scripts in the master question.

Answer (score 8):

To mass convert `.doc` and `.ppt` to `.pdf`, you can use [unoconv](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unoconv/).

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
```

To convert the files you can use the following commands:

```
unoconv -f pdf filename.doc
unoconv -f pdf filename.ppt
unoconv -f pdf *.doc
unoconv -f pdf *.ppt
```

Answer (score 3):

In open office there is a option **File->Export as PDF** .