# Convert odt file to pdf from the command line using unoconv

Tags: pdf

I've come across unoconv which should do the job but I get the following error:-

```
unoconv -f pdf /home/bill/GWL-letter.odt

unoconv: RuntimeException during import phase:
Office probably died. Unsupported URL </home/bill/GWL-letter.odt>: "from LoadEnv::initializeLoading"
~~
```

GWL-letter.odt opened in Office Writer and exported as pdf.  No problems and the pdf file is good

```
: $ unoconv -f pdf /home/bill/GWL-letter.odt
~~
unoconv: RuntimeException during import phase:
Office probably died. Unsupported URL </home/bill/GWL-letter.odt>: "from LoadEnv::initializeLoading"
```

Answer (score 2):

Install libreoffice-writer if not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer
```

Whether or not [unoconv](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/unoconv) was installed with libreoffice, run it once so it can complete configuration.

Comment: libreoffice-writer is already the newest version (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)

Comment: You can try to run libreoffice once (just `libreoffice` will do). It happened to me once, just one run and then unoconv started to work.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the unsupported URL thing

Comment: @bill-lancaster Please open a sample document with LibreOffice Write then do File | Export as PDF  as a troubleshooting test, as shown in https://askubuntu.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-convert-an-odt-file-to-a-pdf then let us know the result by going into the question with [edit] underneath the question. Maybe the LibreOffice latest version install went awry. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please add the result of that test into your Question.